# java code that will create 3 child threads and each child thread will print content of a file(pass name of file while creating child threads)us

Tags: java, multithreading

how to write a java code that will create 3 child threads and each child thread will print the content of a file(pass name of file will creating child thread) using Runnable interface?

Comment: This sounds like homework.  Show us the code you have written so far so we can help you.

Comment: [Defining and Starting a Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: The question you need to answer, is how would you do it without a `Thread`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be of the form:

```
 class FileReaderThread implements Runnable {
     ..
     public FileReaderThread (String fileName) {
          ....
     }
     public void run() {
         /read file
     }
 }

 public class MainClass {
       public static void main(..) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new FileReaderThread(...));
            t.start();
            ...
       }
 }
```